# Why can I not ping anything other than localhost:8080/?

Tags: webserver, ping

I cannot ping any other address on the localhost other then the base directory (i.e, when i run `ping localhost:8080/example`, it will not work).  I have also confirmed that the addresses will work in a browser.  I have also made sure that the firewall settings will allow this.  I have tried the following:

1. `ping localhost:8080/example`
2. `ping localhost/example`
3. `ping 127.0.0.1/example`
4. `ping 0.0.0.0/example` (When trying this I switched the bind address to `0.0.0.0`)
5. `ping 127.0.0.1:8080/example`
6. `ping 0.0.0.0:8080/example` (When trying this I switched the bind address to `0.0.0.0`)

All of these commands result in the same error: `cannot resolve <IP>: unknown host`

My hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

How do I ping anything other the `localhost`?

Comment: This isn’t an Apple or macOS related question so, it’s technically off topic.  However, you’re using `ping` incorrectly.  You `ping` hosts like `localhost` or `apple.com` or IP addresses like `192.168.1.1`. You can’t ping ports (`:8080`) or URI  elements (`/foo/bar`).  See the [`ping` manage](https://ss64.com/osx/ping.html)

Comment: So how would I ping something like `localhost/example`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a general networking question and not about Apple Products or Services as defined in the [Help]

Comment: You ping `localhost` only.  You don’t ping ***anything*** but the host.

Comment: This has the earmarks of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Before moving forward, it eould be immensely helpful if you clearly define the problem you’re trying to solve so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ping` works on network level and can be used to check whether a system/host/computer is reachable via IP ("on the internet"), so it needs to be called with an IP address or a hostname as the main parameter (`ping localhost`, `ping google.com`).

If you want to check whether a specific URL (like `http://localhost:8080/example`) is accessible, you can use tools like `curl` or `wget`.